# Reading from CSV file in scala

Tags: scala, csv

I have a file in that has different data informations about a certain population.

Example of file format:

```
1880,Mary,F,7065
1880,Anna,F,2604
1880,Emma,F,2003
1880,Elizabeth,F,1939
```

*We can interpret this data as “In the year 1880, 7065 female babies were born named Mary"*

I have a function that reads from the file

```
fromFile(name:String):List[List[String]]
```

fromFile returns a list of lists:

List( List("1880","Mary", "F","7065"))

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the data and parsing it out for a function like this, which takes a nested list and a number,and returns a list of of entries of such year.
 For example if 'n' is 1880, then the return list would return all info about Mary.

```
 object readFile{
  val years = CSV.fromFile("my_file.csv") 

def yearIs(data: List[List[String]], n: Int): List[List[String]] = 
      ??
}
```

I trying to figure out how to access each element in the returned list and compare it to the given 'int', and return all the data.

Comment: You can split the line using the comma separator, it will give an array in which you have the line data.

Comment: if( n == line.split(",").map(._trim)), is this what you mean?

Comment: Your code seems a bit confused. `yearIs` takes a `data` parameter, but your code uses `years`.. From your comment, the `line.split` will return an array of entries, so you can't just compare to `n`. But it's not clear that you need to split at all, since `fromFile` seems to return a list of lists of strings, presumably a list of rows each with multiple strings?

Comment: You need to give a complete example of what you want, it will be more clear for us.

Comment: Years variable that reads the file. Should it not be there?

Comment: Ok. I've edited it. Hopefully it will be clearer.

Comment: It was pretty clear what `fromFile` was doing before. But you can't call `getLines` on the result of `fromFile`, which is what `years` is. And you're still not using `data`. As @alifirat says, please provide a more complete example  (maybe the complete assignment question :-P)

Comment: use tabulate http://nrinaudo.github.io/tabulate/ or Faster XML Jackson XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always recommend to first convert input data into a appropriate structure and doing all conversions and possibly error reporting and then do what you want to do on that.

So an appropriate structure for one record would be:

```
case class Record(year: Int, name: String, female: Boolean, count: Int)
```

Lets convert your data:

```
val data = CSV.fromFile("my_file.csv").map {
  case List(year, name, female, count) =>
    Record(year.toInt, name, female == "F", count.toInt)
}
```

You should catch a MatchError and a NumberFormatException here or try to detect these error, if you do care about error handling.

Now we can define your method yearIs in a type-safe and concise manner:

```
def yearIs(data: List[Record], year: Int) = data.filter(_.year == year)
```

You could also directly create a Map from years to list of recors:

```
val byYear: Map[Int, List[Record]] = data.record.groupBy(_.year)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to get "a list of the years from n onward" is to compare `n` with the year or first element in the List using `filter`.

```
scala> def yearIs(data: List[List[String]], n: Int): List[List[String]] = {
     | data.filter(xs => xs.head.toInt > n)
     | }
yearIs: (data: List[List[String]], n: Int)List[List[String]]

scala> yearIs(data, 1880)
res6: List[List[String]] = List()

scala> yearIs(data, 1879)
res7: List[List[String]] = List(List(1880, Mary, F, 7065), List(1880, Anna, F, 2604), List(1880, Emma, F, 2003))
```